# DATABASE_URL undefined node.js

Tags: node.js

I config DATABASE_URL in my dashboard.
When I do in my prompt heroku config

I get:

```
miguel@miguel-VirtualBox:~/Escritorio/mis_proyectos/quiz$ heroku config
=== quiz-miguel2015 Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:               postgres://fudidvccwppmri:Ki28zZ00ikrE43UBcKT1YnQLwb@ec2-54-83-18-87.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d4fh6o7fu6cv5q
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD_URL: postgres://fudidvccwppmri:Ki28zZ00ikrE43UBcKT1YnQLwb@ec2-54-83-18-87.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d4fh6o7fu6cv5q
NODE_ENV:                   production
```

but I get this fail:

```
undefined

/home/miguel/Escritorio/mis_proyectos/quiz/models/models.js:5
var url = process.env.DATABASE_URL.match(/(.*)\:\/\/(.*?)\:(.*)@(.*)\:(.*)\/(.
                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

My file where I get the fail models.js

```
var path = require('path');
// Postgres DATABASE_URL = postgres://user:passwd@host:port/database
// SQLite   DATABASE_URL = sqlite://:@:/
console.dir(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
var url = process.env.DATABASE_URL.match(/(.*)\:\/\/(.*?)\:(.*)@(.*)\:(.*)\/(.*)/);
```

I have created my file .env with the following values in the root :

```
DATABASE_URL=sqlite://:@:/
DATABASE_STORAGE=quiz.sqlite
```

Here I get the complete log:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/miguel/Escritorio/mis_proyectos/quiz/models/models.js:5:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/miguel/Escritorio/mis_proyectos/quiz/controllers/quiz_controller.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

the code is in => https://github.com/Mangulomx/Quiz

Comment: Can you say when that happens? Is is possible that DATABASE_URL is not loaded yet, at the time you try to access it ?

Comment: How are you starting your application?

Comment: npm start I am starting my application. My application is MVC